# Как получить код возврата процесса из конвейера в этом же конвейере?

Tags: linux, bash

Пусть есть конвейер (пайп)

```
false | true | echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

Я расчитывал получить `1` как код возврата `false`, но получаю код возврата команды, выполненой до этого конвейера, т.к. его `PIPESTATUS` еще не сформирован, насколько я понял.

Возможно ли прямо в текущем конвейере оперировать кодами возврата других его команд?

Изначальная цель - для раскрашивания вывода на основе кода возврата предыдущей команды. Можно сделать через хранение вывода во временном файле, но интересует возможнсь через конвейер.

```
echo -e "foo\nbar" | awk -v EXIT_CODE=$? '{ if(EXIT_CODE != 0) { VRB="\033[0;31m"; } else { VRB="\033[0;32m"; } print VRB $0 "\033[0m"; }'
```

Comment: пока какое-то событие не произошло, о его результатах можно строить лишь прогнозы. пока процесс не завершил работу, код возврата от этого процесса получить невозможно. это же банальная причинно-следственная связь.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin во время выполнения `echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` процесс `false` еще не завершил работу?

Comment: нет, процесс ещё на завершил работу. конвейер — это запуск всех перечисленных процессов одновременно. процесс echo получает первым аргументом то, что содержится в переменной `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` **до запуска** конвейера. а вот так получите то значение, которое сформируется **после** завершения работы конвейера: `false | true ; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}`.

Answer (score 0):

Такое решение придумал

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

function dummy {
    echo -e "Random\ntext!!!" "$@"
    return $(($RANDOM % 2))
}

function colored_output {
    TMPF=`mktemp /tmp/.file$$XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`
    TMP=`"$@" >"$TMPF" 2>&1 && echo 0 || echo 1`
    awk -v EXIT_CODE=$TMP '{ if(EXIT_CODE != 0) { VRB="\033[0;31m"; } else { VRB="\033[0;32m"; } print VRB $0 "\033[0m"; }' $TMPF
    rm $TMPF
    if [ $TMP == 1 ]; then
            ! echo $- | grep -q e
    fi
}

echo FOOTEXT > /tmp/f\\noo
colored_output cat /tmp/f\\noo
rm /tmp/f\\noo
colored_output dummy "\n" Foo "\n" Bar "\n" Baz
echo OK
```

Comment: 1. *Useless use of cat*. 2. Predictable temporary file name. 3. `\n` ­— разрешённый символ в имени файла.

Comment: @0andriy благодарю. Так лучше?

Comment: Лучше, но всё же... 1) Каталог для временных файлов лучше использовать системный, т.е. его не нужно указывать при создании временного файла. 2) Потом зачем тут `bash`? Можно же наверняка использовать `sh`. 3) ну и так далее. `sh` и варианты — весьма сложный ЯП, чтобы его правильно использовать, так что не расстраивайтесь, 99% кода на shell — говнокод.